# Proper on-off-on switch wiring advice

Tags: power-supply, switches

i am making a pocket power supply and hoping to use it as voltmeter as well using 3 position SPDT switch to choose between power supply, off or voltmeter.

> [power supply - off - voltmeter]

how do i achieve this and make the middle position of the switch to power it off or should i just use a separate switch for the display?

[image: pocket power]

Comment: there is no over-discharge or short-circuit protection on your battery?

Comment: Use separate switches: Then you can use it as a voltmeter with or without PSU, or as a PSU with or without voltmeter. It's both simpler and more flexible. But yeah, you should probably implement some output protection for the battery.

Comment: oh no - my tp4056 is the older/cheaper version - only control the charge no protection. can i use a one-way diode to prevent the voltage feedback or do you think i should get a proper battery protection module?

Comment: That depends on how much you value your battery, and/or how much you trust your ability to consistently protect the battery using no additional circuitry except your own brain.

Answer (score 1):

Most elegant solution is probably to use a 3P3T toggle or slide switch such as [this](http://spec_sheets.e-switch.com/specs/P040290.pdf) 4P3T one from e-switch:

[image]

Use one pole to control the connection of meter to either the voltmeter lead or the DC-DC output (as you show it), a second pole to control power to the boost converter ('on' only in one position), and a third pole to control power to the DVM ('on' except center position). In the case of the slide switch that leaves one pole spare.

That allows the boost converter to be powered down when only using the voltmeter, saving some battery life (and preventing it from outputting voltage on the output lead when it is not desired).

As the others have suggested use an 18650 with full internal battery protection PCB using MOSFETs and an IC (they're a few mm longer) not an unprotected cell.

Comment: i will use proper battery as advised but is it possible to use a 3p3t dip-switch instead? had it for over a year since my failed attempt to learn how to use it.

Comment: I don't think 3P3T are that common. A 3PDT center-off toggle will work. See the schematic [here](https://www.e-switch.com/system/asset/product_line/data_sheet/129/100.pdf)